# Basic question about ideals in a polynomial ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, commutative-algebra

I would be very grateful if someone would verify or refute the following solution.

Many thanks!

---

Q) Find infinitely many distinct ideals of $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ which contain the principal ideal $(X^3-Y^2).$

A) Consider the ideals $I_n=(X^3-Y^2,\,X^n)$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$

It is clear that $(X^3-Y^2)\subseteq I_n$ and $I_{n}\supseteq I_{n+1}$ for all $n.$

We solve the given problem by proving that $I_{n}\neq I_{n+1}$ for all $n.$

Suppose, for contradiction, that $X^n \in I_{n+1};\;$ that is, there exist $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ such that

$$X^n=(X^3-Y^2)f(X,Y)+X^{n+1}g(X,Y) \hspace{2em} (*).$$

Consider the ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{C}[X,Y]\to\mathbb{C}[T]$ defined by

1. $\,\phi(a)=a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{C},$
2. $\,\phi(X)=T^2,$
3. $\,\phi(Y)=T^3.$

Applying $\phi$ to $(*)$ yields

$$T^{2n}=T^{2n+2}g(T^2,T^3)$$

which is nonsense since the degrees do not match. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a correct and nice proof. Note that you can replace 1. by requiring $\phi$ to be a morphism of $\mathbf{C}$-algebras. But it is only a matter of terminology.

You can also say $\dim_{\mathbf{C}} \mathbf{C}[X,Y]/I_n = 2n$ (there is an obvious basis).

Comment: Many thanks for confirming and also pointing out the slick dimension argument :)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a geometrically flavored solution: The curve given by $X^3-Y^2$ has infinitely many points, namely $(t^2,t^3)$ lies on this curve for any $t \in \mathbb C$.

By the Nullstellensatz, points on the curve correspond to maximal ideals, that contain $(X^3-Y^2)$, i.e. the maximal ideals $(X-t^2,Y-t^3)$ contain $(X^3-Y^2)$ for any $t \in \mathbb C$. So we have found infinitely many maximal ideals that contain $(X^3-Y^2)$.

Actually, we can generalize this: Over $\mathbb C$, any non-constant polynomial $f \in \mathbb C[X,Y]$ has infinitely many zeroes, i.e. any principal ideal not equal to $(1)$ admits infinitely many maximal ideals containing it.